# Only render rooms with the cheapest price for each hotel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, querying

I am retrieving a certain set of rooms from my database. A room belongs_to an hotel. I am retrieving only the rooms that belong to an hotel that is close (20km) to the requested area, I am also checking if the room has the right capacity. This renders me a certain set of rooms (sometimes many rooms for each hotel). Id like to render only one room that match the criterias for each hotel : the one with the cheapest `room_price`. How can I do that ?

Here's how my method looks like so far

```
  def find_hotels
    # hotels near query
    @hotels = Hotel.near(params[:place], 20)
    number_of_people = params[:adults_number].to_i + params[:children_number].to_i
    # rooms with the right capaciy
    # rooms with the best price
    @rooms = Room.where(hotel_id: @hotels.map(&:id)).where("capacity >= :number_of_people", {number_of_people: number_of_people})
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this ?

```
def find_hotels
    # hotels near query
    @hotels = Hotel.near(params[:place], 20)
    number_of_people = params[:adults_number].to_i + params[:children_number].to_i
    # rooms with the right capaciy
    # rooms with the best price
    list_of_rooms = @hotels.inject({}){|result, hotel| result[hotel.id] = cheapest_room_id(hotel.id, number_of_people); result}
  end

def cheapest_room_id(hotel_id, number_of_people)
  return Room.where(hotel_id: hotel_id).where("capacity > ?", number_of_people).order("room_price ASC").first.id
end
```

the variable `list_of_rooms` will contain an hash in this form:

```
{ hotel_1 => room_123, hotel_2 => room_44, hotel_3 => room_666 }
```

everything here is an ID.

PS: it should work.

Comment: this only gives you the cheapest _room of all no the cheapest room for each hotel...

Comment: @DavidGeismar Sorry, misread your question. I updated my answer.

Comment: find_by returns a single instance but otherwise it's working well, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess you might consider that there could be more than one room with equal minimum price in the hotel.

Anyway, if you have 100 hotels to consider then you might find that running one query per hotel to find the cheapest room is not acceptable.

If so, you might have to dip into SQL to optimise the search (and you can also optimise by combining the queries to find the hotels and the query to find the rooms as well, incidentally).

Something like this ought to be performant.

```
def find_hotels
  # hotels near query
  number_of_people = params[:adults_number].to_i + params[:children_number].to_i
  # rooms with the right capaciy
  # rooms with the best price
  @rooms = Room.where(hotel: Hotel.near(params[:place], 20)).
                where("capacity >= :number_of_people", {number_of_people: number_of_people}).
                where("not exists (select null
                                     from rooms r2
                                    where r2.hotel_id   =  rooms.hotel_id    and
                                          r2.capacity   >= :number_of_people and
                                          r2.room_price <= rooms.room_price  and
                                          r2.id         <= rooms.id)", , {number_of_people: number_of_people})
end
```

It find the rooms for which there does not exist another in the same hotel with the required capacity and a cheaper price. In fact, it goes a bit further on the assumption that you only want a single room returned per hotel.

If you want all rooms at the cheapest rate returned, use:

```
def find_hotels
  # hotels near query
  number_of_people = params[:adults_number].to_i + params[:children_number].to_i
  # rooms with the right capaciy
  # rooms with the best price
  @rooms = Room.where(hotel: Hotel.near(params[:place], 20)).
                where("capacity >= :number_of_people", {number_of_people: number_of_people}).
                where("not exists (select null
                                     from rooms r2
                                    where r2.hotel_id   =  rooms.hotel_id    and
                                          r2.capacity   >= :number_of_people and
                                          r2.room_price < rooms.room_price)", , {number_of_people: number_of_people})
end
```

Comment: awesome query skills. ;)

Comment: @RareFever But arguably still not as efficient as it might be though, but within the constraints of a reasonably Rails-ey approach ti would probably do. :)